# Pretty printing in windows command line

Tags: python, clint

I am trying to add colors to my input statement in the windows command line using the library Clint.

```
from clint.textui import colored, puts,prompt

puts(colored.yellow("Hello!!!\n\n"))
user_number = prompt.query(str(colored.cyan('\nPlease enter something:\n')))
```

I can't figure out why the cyan color not showing up. Attached is the view from the command line. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What version of windows are you on? This is only supported in some windows 10 versions

Comment: I am using Windows 10 Pro

Comment: @ayadav I have added a solution to your problem, pls take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the definition of the query function in the file prompt.py from the clint lib

```
def query(prompt, default='', validators=None, batch=False):
    # Set the nonempty validator as default
    if validators is None:
        validators = [RegexValidator(r'.+')]

    # Let's build the prompt
    if prompt[-1] is not ' ':
        prompt += ' '

    if default:
        prompt += '[' + default + '] '

    # If input is not valid keep asking
    while True:
        # If batch option is True then auto reply
        # with default input
        if not batch:
            user_input = raw_input(prompt).strip() or default
        else:
            print(prompt)
            user_input = ''

        # Validate the user input
        try:
            for validator in validators:
                user_input = validator(user_input)
            return user_input
        except Exception as e:
            puts(yellow(e.message))
```

you can see that you can't print a colorful text like you are trying to achieve, since it expects
a literal string as an argument, we can alter the query function to work as expected like this

```
from clint.textui import colored, puts, prompt, validators as validators_module
from re import match

prompt_colors = {
  "red": colored.red, "green": colored.green, "yellow": colored.yellow, "blue": colored.blue,
  "black": colored.black, "magenta": colored.magenta, "cyan": colored.cyan, "white": colored.white
}

def new_query(prompt, color, default='', validators=None, batch=False):
    # Set the nonempty validator as default
    if validators is None:
        validators = [validators_module.RegexValidator(r'.+')]

    # Let's build the prompt
    if prompt[-1] is not ' ':
        prompt += ' '

    if default:
        prompt += '[' + default + '] '

    # If input is not valid keep asking
    while True:
        # If batch option is True then auto reply
        # with default input
        if not batch:
            # now the output is colored as expected 
            puts(prompt_colors[color](prompt))
            user_input = input().strip() or default
        else:
            print(prompt)
            user_input = ''

        # Validate the user input
        try:
            for validator in validators:
                user_input = validator(user_input)
            return user_input
        except Exception as e:
            puts(yellow(e.message))

# now the query function is customized as per our needs
prompt.query = new_query

puts(colored.yellow("Hello!!!\n\n"))
user_input = prompt.query("Please enter something: ", "cyan")
```

[image]

**Note:** I think the changes are clear enough and do not need explanation, but if you have some questions I would be glad to answer'em in the comments section

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is because [prompt.py](https://github.com/kennethreitz-archive/clint/blob/master/clint/textui/prompt.py#L80) translates your input into a raw string thus not recognising the color that you chose. I think this a bad implementation from their part. You can prove my theory by running
`user_number = prompt.query(str(colored.cyan('\nPlease enter something:\n')),batch=True)`
This is an infinite loop but it prints your color just because it is not translated into raw in this [case](https://github.com/kennethreitz-archive/clint/blob/master/clint/textui/prompt.py#L82).

Comment: I guess your right. Is there any other library which will be suitable for my case?

Comment: That's what I would do:  ```puts(colored.yellow("Please enter a string:\n"))  

value = input()```  @ayadav

Comment: Oh yeah simple and sweet. Thanks!

Comment: @ayadav I would appreciate an upvote on my answer. You are welcome :)